# Groovy; Annotation type cannot be inner

Tags: groovy, bean-validation

I create my validator interface to validate two bean properties are matched using following code :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE )
@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldMatchesValidator.class)
@Documented

 @interface FieldMatches {

    String fieldName();

    String dependFieldName();

    String message() default "{FieldMatches.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default [];

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default [];


   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Target(ElementType.TYPE )
   @Documented
    @interface List {
       FieldMatches[] value();
   }

}
```

In annotations, I'd expect something like:

```
 @FieldMatches.List([
        @FieldMatches(
                fieldName = "pass",
                dependFieldName = "confpass1"),
        @FieldMatches(
                fieldName = "pass",
                dependFieldName = "confpass1")
    ])
```

With this, i receive the following error:

```
Annotation type cannot be inner
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace? Does it make a difference if you add the 'public' keyword?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `@interface List { ... }` into its own class - it can't be a nested class.